# Qt command line compilation fails at linker stage with garbage NXCOMPAT data

Tags: c++, windows, qt, linker

I am compiling a program using Qt 5.9 on Windows 10 with the Visual Studio cl.exe compiler.  The program is cross platform, and the Mac version (built with clang) builds fine.

The instruction is:

```
qmake.exe Project-Test.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" && jom.exe
```

After the moc and .o files are generated, the linker begins with:

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:release\Project-Test.exe @C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Project-Test.exe.7920.282.jom
```

And then immediately fails with:

```
link: extra operand ÔÇÿ/NXCOMPATÔÇÖ
Try 'link --help' for more information.
jom: C:\Users\User\ProjectName\Project-AppAndTest\Project-Test\Makefile.Release [release\Project-Test.exe] Error 1
```

I have tried various combinations of qmake and jom with no discernable difference.  My feeling is that there is some environmental variable that is missing or incorrect.
NXCOMPAT appears to relate to whether the software is runnable on the PC.  I do have some platform dependent sections of code (if PC do x, if Mac do y) however as it compiles and links with the exact same command above, in the gui, I think that this is not the cause.

I have tested this deployment on two different computers and the same error is occurring.

Some clarifications about would be answers-

The program builds and runs fine from the gui, but the program is supposed to be built and executed as part of a batch file, and can't involve the gui in any way.

I am using the library QWebEngine, which currently cannot be compiled with MinGW, so I'm stuck to using Visual Studio/Cl.

The platform is 64 bit but the program includes 32 bit libraries so must be compilied using the win32-msvc flag.

I have tried running the software using vcvarsall.bat however this appears to break Qt include path settings and the program will not compile without modifying all #includes to explicitly indicate where the header is located.

I'm hoping to get some information on what could be causing this error and how I could go about resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the mingw linker being added silently to the bash path.

I had been building the software under git bash which appears to prepend the MinGW linker to the path; so when the link command was called it was using the GNU linker instead of the MSVC linker.

I was able to get around this by exporting the intended path before executing the build.